# render on header p:layoutUnit does not work (primefaces)

Tags: primefaces

I want to modify the header of the p:layoutUnit with a render such as

```
<p:layoutUnit header="#{msg['layout.new']}" rendered="#{editBean.edition == false}"> 
<p:layoutUnit header="#{msg['layout.edit']}" rendered="#{editBean.edition == true}">
```

But it does not seem to wrok (the primefaces page cannot open anymore).
Where did I make a mistake ?

(I am pretty sure that editBean.edition is initialized to either true or false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution this way:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center">  

 <p:panel rendered="#{editBean.edition == false}" header="#{msg['layout.new']}" styleClass="panelTitle">

 </p:panel>

 <p:panel rendered="#{editBean.edition == true}" header="#{msg['layout.editM']}" styleClass="panelTitle">

 </p:panel>

 ...
 </p:layoutUnit>
```